# Deriving the modified geodesic eq. in scalar-tensor theory

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, geodesics

In scalar-tensor theory, we have the field equations

$$G_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi}{\phi} T_{\mu\nu} + \frac{\omega(\phi)}{\phi^2} \left ( \phi_{,\mu} \phi_{,\nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} \phi_{,\lambda} \phi^{,\lambda} \right ) + \frac{1}{\phi} \left ( \phi_{;\mu\nu} - g_{\mu\nu} \Box_g \phi \right ) \,, 
\label{fieldeq1}\\
\Box_g \phi  = \frac{1}{3 + 2\omega(\phi)} \left ( 8\pi T - 16\pi \phi \frac{\partial T}{\partial \phi} - \frac{d\omega}{d\phi} \phi_{,\lambda} \phi^{,\lambda} \right ) \,.$$

Setting the energy-momentum-tensor to

$$T^{\mu\nu} (x^\alpha) = (-g)^{-1/2} \sum_A \int d\tau M_A (\phi) u_A^\mu u_A^\nu \delta^4 (x_A^\alpha (\tau) - x^\alpha)  
\nonumber \\
= (-g)^{-1/2} \sum_A M_A (\phi) u_A^\mu u_A^\nu (u_A^0)^{-1} 
\delta^3 ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_A) \,,$$

we have the eq. of motion

$${T^{\mu\nu}}_{;\nu} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial \phi} \phi^{,\mu} \,.$$

I understand that. The author then goes on to say that one can write the eq. of motion as

$$u^\nu \nabla_\nu (M_A(\phi) u^\mu ) = - \frac{dM_A}{d\phi} \phi^{,\mu} \,,$$

and

$$\frac{dv^j}{dt} + \Gamma^j_{\alpha\beta} v^\alpha v^\beta
-\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} v^\alpha v^\beta v^j 
= - \frac{1}{M_A(u^0)^2} \frac{dM_A}{d\phi} ( \phi^{,j} - \phi^{,0} v^j ) \,.$$

I don't understand how one derives the last two equations, anyone any pointers on that maybe? (Also the author says that one could get the last equation directly from the matter action $\int_A M_A(\phi)d\tau$ but I don't know how either).

Comment: Have you tried plugging $T^{\mu\nu}$ as given in the e.o.m. ? Seems to me you should get there after some algebra. Nothing really mysterious

Comment: I can see that for the first eq, even though my calculations don't add up with the one presented here. But how would I get the second one from the first one?

Comment: There is some sort of 1+3 split, they seem to separate the time direction from the space ones, so a specific form of $u^\mu$ was used which has the 3-velocity $v^i$ as its spatial components

Comment: I agree with that, but I still don't get how they did that. Do you have a specific way in mind? I really appreciate the pointers, though!